# Language and LanguageAdvanced plugin not found on Marfury theme ( laravel - botble theme )

Tags: laravel, content-management-system

i purchase botble martfury theme from evento.
botble doc: https://docs.botble.com/

CMS Version: 5.20
Framework Version: 8.55.0

on the live martfury theme, Language and AdvanceLanguage plugin exist but on purchased theme this plugin is not available
https://martfury.botble.com/admin/plugins

Any one give his solution to integrate LanguageAdvanced plugin,
basically i want this on product create/edit page on admin
like user can see product name in different language

Answer (score 0):

read about **localiztion** here [localization](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/localization)

and put any lang you want

I think this docs is enough